# Prepared MySQLi statements in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Sorry if I seem new to this.

```
        if(!isset($stmt_counttime)) { $stmt_counttime = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT count(1) as count FROM `stop_times` where `stop_id` = ? and `trip_id` = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt_counttime->bind_param('ss',$stop_id,$trip_id); }
    $stop_id = $data[3];
    $trip_id = $data[0];
    $stmt_counttime->execute();
    $stmt_counttime->bind_result($count_time_result);
    $stmt_counttime->fetch();

    if(!isset($stmt_counttrip)) { $stmt_counttrip = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT count(1) as count FROM `trips` where `trip_id` = ?");
    $stmt_counttrip->bind_param('s',$tripid);
     }

    $tripid = $data[0];
    $stmt_counttrip->execute();
    $stmt_counttrip->bind_result($count_trip_result);
    $stmt_counttrip->fetch();
```

Line 67: $stmt_counttrip->bind_param('s',$tripid);

Error: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/fallouta/public_html/ocbus/google_transit/stop_times.php on line 67

If anyone could let me know, what I am doing wrong? Please let me know.

Note: I need trip_id's value as string not integer.

Thanks,
Cyrus

Answer (score 3):

I realized my mistake. One should include the following statement:

$stmt->store_result();

Because you can't have two queries simultaneously. Feel free to add more information.

Answer (score 1):

first set params, then bind them:

```
$stop_id = $data[3];
$trip_id = $data[0];
$stmt_counttime->bind_param('ss',$stop_id,$trip_id);
```

and

```
$tripid = $data[0];
$stmt_counttrip->bind_param('s',$tripid);
```

at least that is what php.net recommends